# How do I put storage quota limitation on storage class

Tags: kubernetes, quota, kubernetes-pvc

I want to dynamically create `PeristentVolumes` and mount them into my pod using PVCs. SO, I am following kubernetes Dynamic Provisioning concept. I am creating `PersistentVolumeClaim` using Kubernetes `StorageClasses`.

I am creating PVC using `StorageClasses` like this.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: test-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
```

Now, I want to put restriction on StorageClasses `test-sc` to limit storage usage. In any case, the sum of storage used by PVCs which are created using StorageClass `test-sc` across all namespaces should not exceed 150M.

I am able to limit the storage usage of PVCs created using StorageClass `test-sc` for single namespace as following.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: quota-limit-sc
  namespace: test
spec:
  hard:
    secure-maprfs.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage: 150Mi
```

How do I put this limitation on Cluster Level i.e. on Storage Classes ??

Answer (score 0):

This is applicable per namespace only.
You will have to define quotas for all your namespaces